# Array "includes" method fails in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was trying to use the "includes" method for an array in Google Apps Script but it fails with "Cannot find function includes in object 1,4,3,7. (line 4, file "test_array"). Here is the code:

```
    function test_array() {
    var array1 = [1,4,3,7];
    Logger.log(Array.isArray(array1)); // returns true
    var proof = array1.includes("A"); 
     // proof fails with "Cannot find function includes in object 1,4,3,7. 
     // (line 4, file "test_array")
  Logger.log(proof);
}
```

In the logs I see that the Logger.log() returns true. I worked around this with:

```
function test_array() {
  var array1 = [1,4,3,7];
  Logger.log(Array.isArray(array1)); // returns true
  var proof = array1.indexOf("A"); // Works fine
  Logger.log(proof);
}
```

But I still want to know why the includes method fails on a variable the compiler says is an array. Could it be that it is considering it to be an array of arrays, i.e. an object?

Thanks,

Comment: what does `includes` return, if it fails?

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` is fairly recent, the version of js is probably older.

Comment: Unfortunately, [this cannot be used at GAS in the current stage.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) Because [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) has been added to ECMAScript 2015.

Comment: Hi Nina, it returns true if element is found or false if it is not.

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for your reply. So it looks like GAS is using an older version of JS?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Use `indexOf` instead.

Comment: You may also use a polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

It was/is not supported in [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino) runtime. [With upgrade](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#modern_javascript_features) to [v8](/questions/tagged/v8), [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is supported and should be preferred instead of `Array.indexOf` in all cases.