# TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object (even though the object is an array)

Tags: google-apps-script

Why does app scripts not find the function includes in the object that is clearly an Array.

```
function test() {
  var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  Logger.log(list.constructor.name) // Array
    if ( list.includes('a') ){
      Logger.log('yes');
    } 
 return 'done';
}
```

The error text:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object a,b,c. (line 134, file "Code")
```

I am new with google app scripts and I am getting mad. I have tried it in a online Javascript console and everything is fine.

Comment: Google Apps Script is JavaScript 1.6, not EMCAScript2017. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/50281560/9337071

Answer (score 6):

Due to the comment that helped, this is an alternative solution.

```
function test() {
  var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  Logger.log(list.constructor.name) // Array
  if ( list.indexOf('a') > -1 ){
      Logger.log('Yes'); // 'Yes'
  } 
return 'done';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this thread to create this function for this purpose.

```
function includesReplacement(theArrayOrHaystack, theItemOrNeedle) {
 return (theArrayOrHaystack.indexOf(theItemOrNeedle) > -1);
}
```