# GSA error: Cannot find function includes in object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 2 array and i want find in first array have value of second array is push data of first array but i can't.

Error message : "TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object...."

This my code:

```
function loadArrInArr(){

  var firstArr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urldb);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var secondArr = ws.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var tmpArr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < secondArr.length; i++){
    if(firstArr.includes(secondArr[i][0])){ //err this line
      tmpArr.push(secondArr[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I found this thread. I think that this thread is useful for your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50281560/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike tks you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `includes()` cannot be used with Google Apps Script yet. So how about this modification? In this modification, `indexOf` is used instead of `includes`.

### Pattern 1:

When your script is modified, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
if(firstArr.includes(secondArr[i][0])){
```

#### To:

```
if(firstArr.indexOf(secondArr[i][0]) > -1){
```

or

```
if(~firstArr.indexOf(secondArr[i][0])){
```

### Pattern 2:

As another pattern, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var tmpArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < secondArr.length; i++){
  if(firstArr.includes(secondArr[i][0])){ //err this line
    tmpArr.push(secondArr[i]);
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
var tmpArr = secondArr.filter(function(row) {return ~firstArr.indexOf(row[0])});
```

- When the length of `secondArr` is large, to use `filter()` can reduce the process cost than that of the for loop.

#### References:

- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [Benchmark: Loop for Array Processing using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)

If I misunderstood your question and this wat not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tested it and succeeded. You're so good !

Comment: @Naoa Lee Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I added one more script. Could you please confirm it? The additional script is faster than the script using the for loop.

Comment: Tks you so much, Please give me the link !

Comment: @Naoa Lee The additional script is "Pattern 2" in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, ^^ Thank you for your enthusiasm !